# How can clear the cache in using table.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, sqlalchemy, drop

List all tables in database `sample`:

```
from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
db_pass = 'xxxxxx'
db_ip='127.0.0.1'
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:{}@{}/sample'.format(db_pass,db_ip))
inspector = inspect(engine)
print(inspector.get_table_names())
['pre', 'sample']
```

Now drop the table `pre`:

```
metadata = MetaData()
pre_table = Table('pre', metadata)
pre_table.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
```

Type `\d` when to enter into psql, only one table shown in `sample` database:

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=# \c  sample
You are now connected to database "sample" as user "postgres".
sample=# \d
public | sample                       | table    | postgres
```

The table `pre` already dropped! But `print(inspector.get_table_names())` (type the second time) still shows two tables in the database:

```
print(inspector.get_table_names())
['pre', 'sample']
```

How can clear the cache in using `table.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `inspector.clear_cache()` method?

`inspector` object is backed by the [`PGInspector`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/671647c8574bd6ff4c39fe503a2b1958a802772d/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#LL2700C7-L2700C18) class which inherits from [`reflection.Inspector`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/671647c8574bd6ff4c39fe503a2b1958a802772d/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py#L173). And the later implements this [`clear_cache()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/671647c8574bd6ff4c39fe503a2b1958a802772d/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py#LL260C9-L260C20) method.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this. I don't have PostgresSQL setup for it. Please comment if this works.*

Answer (score 1):

You can "clear the cache" by creating a new instance of the `inspector` object:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")
table_name = "so76151021"

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (id int)")

inspector = sa.inspect(engine)
print(inspector.get_table_names())
# ['so76151021']

tbl = sa.Table(table_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)

print(inspector.get_table_names())
# ['so76151021']

inspector = sa.inspect(engine)  # create new instance
print(inspector.get_table_names())
# []
```